# Getting always the same Hash with Node.js and Multer

Tags: node.js, hash, md5, multer, sha256

I've tried to change multer/storage/disk.js file so I can storage a hash everytime I upload a file, but the fact is that I'm always getting the same hash even uploading different files.

This is what I've done.

```
DiskStorage.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {

  var that = this
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')

  that.getDestination(req, file, function (err, destination) {
    if (err) return cb(err)

    that.getFilename(req, file, function (err, filename) {
      if (err) return cb(err)

      var finalPath = path.join(destination, filename)
      var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(finalPath)

      file.stream.pipe(outStream)
      outStream.on('error', cb)
      outStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        hash.update(chunk)
      })

      outStream.on('finish', function () {
        cb(null, {
          destination: destination,
          filename: filename,
          path: finalPath,
          size: outStream.bytesWritten,
          hash: hash.digest('hex')

        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

It' s like this section isn't doing anything

```
outStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        hash.update(chunk)
      })
```

Comment: You probably want to use `crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("hex")` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually a bit lost, where I'm I supposed to put that?

Comment: You've complained about `crypto.createHash('sha256')` returning the same hash, right?

Comment: Sure but this way I'll get a random hash, but If I want to upload a file already uploeaded (because it's a new version) I should get the same hash

Comment: hello,i have the some problem. Would you pleace tell me how to replace the DiskStorage?

Answer (score 1):

There's a discussion about this issue in Multers github:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/248

microacup posted this about suhaotion's code ( which looks like yours )

```
DiskStorage.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {
...
  file.stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
      hash.update(chunk)
  })

...
```

instead of

```
DiskStorage.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {
...
  outStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
      hash.update(chunk)
  })

...
```